# Why ListView.getChildCount()==0 (always)?

Tags: android, listview, spannablestring

I want set a SpannableString to some item of the ListView when the activity create.
I write it like this:

```
    doListlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.dolist_List);
    listsDbAdapter=new yueDataBaseAdapter(this);
    listsDbAdapter.open();
    UpdataAdpter();

    for(int i = 0; i < doListlist.getChildCount(); i++) {  
        if (listsDbAdapter.fetchData(tableName, i+1).getString(7).length() == 4) {

          View view = doListlist.getChildAt(i);  

          String drawText=listsDbAdapter.fetchData(tableName,i+1).getString(1);

          TextView txtInfo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.doList_itemname);

          SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(drawText); 
          ss.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 0, drawText.length(),  Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
          txtInfo.setText(ss);
        }
    }

    public void UpdataAdpter(){
    Cursor cur= listsDbAdapter.fetchAllData(tableName);
    if(cur!=null&& cur.getCount()>=0){
        adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.dolist_item,
                cur,
                new String[]{yueDataBaseAdapter.KEY_NAME,yueDataBaseAdapter.KEY_PRICESTR,yueDataBaseAdapter.KEY_NUMSTR},
                new int[]{R.id.doList_itemname,R.id.doList_itemPrice,R.id.doList_itemNum}
        );

        doListlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

but I find that doListlist.getChildCount() always = 0.
Where is the question? Or any other better way to do this?

Comment: You list isn't being populated correctly. Show the code you're using t populate it.

Comment: try using doListList.getAdapter().getCount().

Answer (score 0):

because you've not set the list's adapter yet. do

```
doListlit.setAdapter(listsDbAdapter);
```

first, before calling `getChildCount`.

Comment: sorry i missed that. were you able to check the value of cursor.getCount()?

Comment: I write it like this:
         for(int i = 0; i < doListlist.getCount(); i++){...}    
        doListlist.getCount() is useful,but it has a new question!
        the code stop at :
         TextView txtInfo =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.doList_itemname);

Answer (score 0):

**check this out:**

[getChildCount() returns 0 on ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699286/getchildcount-returns-0-on-listview)

It worked for me.
I hope it will be helpful